# Gauging Wire for 12V Parallel Circuit

Tags: parallel, wire, gauge

I'm building a 12V parallel circuit to run some LEDs...I simplified it in the picture below but need some advice on wire sizing in a parallel circuit.

The combined amps of the 3 lights is ~11.25amps.  I had planned to use 18ga wire to wire the lights...and splice them together after the switches so I could control them individually.

Can someone coach me through gauging the wire?

[image]

Comment: It's going to depend on the temperature rating of the wire insulation, and the rating of your fuse.  Please add that information to your question.   I also note that there is a serious error in your diagram:  When any switch is off, the battery will be short-circuited and the fuse will [hopefully] blow.  (BTW, the built-in schematic editor on this SE will give more readable diagrams with standard symbols.)

Comment: AWG#18 look too small. You can run each d separately and connect together at fuse. And you should worry about drop voltage on wires.

Comment: I can adapt the fuse size and wire as appropriate...looking for guidance on what I should do.  I suppose you know what I’m aiming to do...is it better to ask how I can accomplish this with switches for each light in parallel?

Comment: Please correct me but as I’m learning I believe all wired need to be able to handle the combined current so 18 is too small.  Concerning the fuse, how do I handle that without short circuit

Comment: @Theodore: if the OP is using illuminated SPST switches, the negative connections on the switches are correct.  If he is using SPDT switches, then the negative connections on the switches are indeed wrong, and should be removed.

Comment: They are in fact illuminated SPST...so no fuse concerns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to take a look at an ampacity chart.  They show the maximum current a conductor can carry based on how hot you want to allow it to get (i.e. before it starts melting insulation).  There are several caveats:

1: The temperatures in the chart are all based on a certain ambient temperature, usually around 30C.  If you plan to operate above this temperature - and you should, 30C is only 86F - you'll have to correct down.  Some charts will have a correction factor on them so you can find the new allowable current.

2: Since no single chart could account for all the possible physical configurations of bundling, sheathing, or otherwise covering the wire, many of them only give values for a single wire in free air, which is the best case.  As soon as you start zip-tying the wire in with other conductors or putting it in conduit, it will be harder for heat to escape from your wire, which reduces the amount of allowable current.  You'll see that the linked chart also gives values for a maximum of three wires bundled together.

3: While the values you will see on an ampacity chart are based on relatively conservative assumptions, remember that they are conservative assumptions for the best case scenario.  Give yourself reasonable buffer.

4: Since I'm a connector and cable guy, I'll put in a note here that you should not neglect your connections - to your battery, your switch, or your loads.  A bad connection can cause hard to diagnose problems or create a dangerous situation, especially once you get out of sub-Amp territory.  Good solder joints and good crimps are the keys to success and it only takes a little practice to get good at them.

Edit: You'll notice I didn't say what size wire to use.  That will depend on your specific wire and what it's insulated with, etc.  But you can see from the chart that 18 AWG is too small for at least the main lines going to and from the battery.

[image: Ampacity Chart]

Ampacity chart from Blue Sea Systems

Comment: I would recommend using the same wire gauge throughout, and sizing it to handle the fuse current.  The fuse rating will be at least the next standard size above the total current.  Good point about the temperature rating of the connectors, and really anything that the wires are going to touch in the assembly (e.g. a plastic enclosure).

Comment: This is helpful! So I had planned to size the wires to the battery up. But I could do same throughout, but is it accurate to say those wires to the battery will receive more current than when it splits...this is more me learning.  Concerning fuse, why does it blow when all switches are off?

Comment: @user3310766 The wires to each individual LED will only carry about 4A, however in case of accidental overload or short-circuit, they will carry as much as the fuse allows.  This is why I recommended using the fuse rating as a basis.  In case you haven't already found it, the insulation jacket of the wire should be printed with a temperature rating (or at least an insulation type that you can reference to temperature.)

Comment: I’m currently looking at the wire here ...I’m thinking I need 12-2? https://www.westmarine.com/WestAdvisor/Marine-Wire-Size-And-Ampacity

Comment: So 150W / 12V is 12.5A....I should use a 15A fuse... 12-2 wire given the chart links above?

Comment: It should, but without knowing the specifics of your installation I can't give you any sort of definitive answer.

Comment: It will be run in 6ft of 3/4” pvc conduit to a aluminum enclosure holding the led chips

Comment: The lights are waterproofed and the aluminum housing is submerged